# Confused about the block scope in loop heads and parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I have read [Variables and scoping in ECMAScript 6](https://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html?tdsourcetag=s_pctim_aiomsg), but I still got some strange output when I execute the codes in browser console below

```
for(let i = 0; i < 0;) {
    var i
}//Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'i' has already been declared
```

```
for(let i = 0; i < 0;) {
    let i
}//undefined
```

Why the first one throws an error?
When I try this in parameter, it goes opposite

```
function foo(x){
    let x
}//Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'x' has already been declared
```

```
function foo(x){
    var x
}//undefined
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Please consult the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Comment: @StefanN I believe the question is fairly clear, that is, why does the first example throw an error, especially given the second set of examples

Comment: First case happens because `i` is hoisted (hence already declared), second happens because `let i` is never reached, third happens because `x` is already binded to an argument, four is ok because `var`s can be redeclared if not in strict mode, if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The first sample throws because

```
for(let i = 0; i < 0;) {
    var i
}
```

is equivalent to the following code due to [hoisting of `var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

```
var i

for(let i = 0; i < 0;) { // <-- throws because `i` has already defined 

}
```

The second sample wont throw because loop body never executes and even if it would for-loop body creates a block scope so it is ok to have another `let i` in it

```
for(let i = 0; i < 0;) {
    throw new Error('Never reached')
    let i
}

for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    let i = 'bar' // ok
    console.log(i)
}
```

The third sample throws because name `x` already binded to an agrument.

```
function foo(x){
    let x // throws because `x` already used
}
```

The last sample is ok because `var` can redefine names

```
function foo(x){
    var x
    var x
    var x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is scoping. var is scoped to the nearest function block and let is scoped to the nearest enclosing block, which can be smaller than a function block. Both are global if outside any block.

Also, variables declared with let are not accessible before they are declared in their enclosing block. As seen in the demo, this will throw a `ReferenceError` exception.

if you want more explanation you can read the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/4972873) with some examples for better understanding,